# printer not working with Ubuntu 20.04, "hpcups not available"

Tags: 20.04, printing

Hp Laserjet 1108, HP Laserjet 1007, HP laserjet pro M1213nf MFP, Canon Pixma 5070, no printers are working after installing Ubuntu 20.04. they all were working in Ubuntu 18.04. it says:

```
File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups" not available: No such file or directory.
```

however terminal says:

```
hplip is already the newest version (3.20.3+dfsg0-2)
```

I also tried `hplip-gui`, and also reinstalled Ubuntu total 4 times over 2 different laptops but still printer is not working.

Comment: Are you missing `printer-driver-hpcups` package? How are you installing hplip: apt or the one from HP website?

Comment: in one computer i have not installed hplip, only installed ubuntu 20.04 and only run update . in other computer i installed hplip from hp website. sudo apt install cups says "cups is already the newest version (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1)."

Comment: sudo apt install printer-driver-hpcups  "printer-driver-hpcups is already the newest version (3.20.3+dfsg0-2)."

Comment: Is that file present there? `ls -lA /usr/lib/cups/filter/|grep cups`

Comment: avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$ ls -lA /usr/lib/cups/filter/|grep cups   "avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$ "

Comment: "Print Error - There was a problem processing document "[name of document] (job x)."

Comment: yes, many many thanks for your guidance. although i had made a fresh installation of ubuntu 20.04 but i have not been able to print from past 2 months around. i wish printer could have run. thank you sir.

Comment: look:
[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346783/1141129)

Answer (score 5):

You're probably missing the shared library `/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups`, according to Debian file list the package `printer-driver-hpcups` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/printer-driver-hpcups/) has it. So if you installed `hplip` from the HP website package, uninstall it using that setup. If via apt or preinstalled in Focal do this:

```
sudo apt purge hplip hplip-gui printer-driver-hpcups
```

Make sure to note what gets removed (read output) do an `apt autoremove` if necessary. Then reinstall them, this way it's less likely to have a broken system.

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui printer-driver-hpcups <+ anything that's removed in the last steps>
```

Then run the printer setup wizard after connecting your printer, make sure CUPS sockets are activated, CUPS services are running; select the `ppd` file if necessary and you can complete the wizard.

Comment: Hay, thank you, this solution saved me a lot of headache under ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS. The "L" in "LTS" actually means that I don't want to care for that problem for a long time and you've contributed to that :)

Comment: This is all very helpful: thanks for that. Just one more piece of information would be useful: what is the name of the "printer setup wizard" executable? (I'm doing this remotely, on  a headless machine.)

Answer (score 1):

With my Epson Stylus Photo R300 printer, I tried everything I could think of until I realised Ubuntu 20.04 was disabling printers at every reboot.
Then "System Settings" | "Printers" / Double click on your printer / Select "Policies" and check the "Enable" box.
This has to be done after each reboot!

Comment: Thanks, for sharing this, since I first tried the first solution before I can not say it was necessary after new install but it was disabled in my config as well. However it kept enabled also after restart in my environment.