# CUPS: `stopped "Filter failed"' when trying to print after ubuntu update

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, 20.10, ghostscript

```
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] PID 20964 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Start rendering...
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Processing page 1...
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Operand stack:
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] true   (/tmp/gs_wO3nvv)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Execution stack:
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   2   3   %oparray_pop   1989   2   3   %oparray_pop   1977   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Dictionary stack:
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] --dict:752/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:135/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:318/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:7/20(L)--
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Current allocation mode is local
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] GPL Ghostscript 9.52: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Rendering completed
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] PID 20961 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] End of messages
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] printer-state=3(idle)
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [15/Apr/2021:02:45:21 -0500] [Job 21] printer-state-reasons=none
```

I updated my ubuntu to 20.10 Groovy Gorilla and now the above happens.

I got the logs above with this command: `sudo tail -n 100 -f /var/log/cups/error_log`

I have tried going to `http://localhost:631` in browser and have deleted and reinstalled printer with every driver for my printer model. The error in cups is always the same `stopped "Filter failed"` after I try printing a test page. The ink level shows up in my printer settings correctly. I can print from this printer from windows on the same pc when I boot from my windows partition.

I have also run the following commands successfully:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo service cups restart

sudo apt-get install hpijs-ppds printer-driver-hpijs

sudo service cups restart

sudo rm /usr/share/ghostscript/9.52/iccprofiles
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common 

sudo service cups restart
```

The printer I bought is: `HP LaserJet Pro M15w Wireless Laser Printer`

The driver I install in CUPS is: `HP LaserJet m14-m17, hpcups 3.21.2 (grayscale)`

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
1) sudo apt purge hplip hplip-gui printer-driver-hpcups
2) sudo apt autoremove
3) sudo apt update 
4) sudo apt upgrade
5) sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui printer-driver-hpcups <+ anything that's removed in the last steps>
6) sudo service cups restart
7) sudo apt-get install hpijs-ppds printer-driver-hpijs
8) sudo service cups restart
9) hp-plugin
```

:) I'm not sure if 7 and 8 is essential... I make all by tips... and nothing, then 9 save me! I have HP cp1025